# I want to change a variable from instantiated objects(sprite with script attached) for each object independently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am making a game and I have a world generated with Perlin-Noise. I spawn trees on a random 'grass' location and then I want to be able to give the tree health so I can chop it.

```
    else if(noise <= 0.43)//gras
   {

        int treeNumber = Random.Range(0,100);
        if(treeNumber <5)
        {
            GameObject makeTree = Instantiate(tree[0], pos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
   }
```

I have a tree sprite wit a script component

```
public static int treesHealth;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    treesHealth = 100;
}
```

I have a player with a 'fight' script

```
public void DoDamage(int amount, int startTreeHealt)
{
    Vector3 origin = playerpos;
    int range = 1;
    RaycastHit2D[] hit = Physics2D.RaycastAll(origin,dir,range);//startpos, direction, range
    for(int i = 0; i < hit.Length; i++)
    {
        if(hit[i].transform.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("nature"))
        {

            Vector3 hitpos = hit[i].transform.position;

            treeHealth.treesHealth = treeHealth.treesHealth - amount; 


            if(treeHealth.treesHealth < 1)
            {
                Destroy(hit[i].transform.gameObject);
                GameObject makeTrunks = Instantiate(treeTrunks, hitpos, Quaternion.identity);

            }

            return;

        }

    }
```

At first it seems to work well but there are 2 scenarios where it goes wrong. when I hit a tree a couple of times (not enough to 'chop it') and walk to another tree.

1. In the time I walk to the other tree I go 'out of screen' and new trees are instantiated.

   - The already hit trees health gets reset it is back to 100
2. In the time I walk to the other tree I don't go 'out of screen' and there aren't new trees instantiated

   - The 2nd, and all other trees have the same health as the already hit tree

I want to be able to hit the trees independently. The trees have to 'remember' how much health they have left.

I'm totally lost on how to achieve this but I think that the script attached to the tree isn't the way I can do this.

I hope someone can help me in the right direction thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The problem is you made treesHealth static.  If you have more than one tree you need a different instance of treesHealth.  Being static all you trees have the same health.

Comment: But when I make it just 'public int treeshealth' then I get this error: Assets\scripts\fight.cs(24,20): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'treeHealth.treesHealth'

Comment: oh and when  I add 'private treeHealth treeHealth;' on the top of the fighting script I get this error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
fight.Update () (at Assets/scripts/fight.cs:41)
on this line 'animator.SetBool("Bool_fight", Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"));'

Comment: I can't tell anything from the code posted.  You need an array of trees where each has a treeHealth.

Comment: I have an array for different trees thats why I instantiate  tree[0]. I tought if it works with tree[0] I can do the same for tree[1]  but than wit another health.

Comment: Not with STATIC.  Static will give same health to all trees.

Comment: @jdweng I solved it you where right, have the trees STATIC was the problem, if you put it in an answer I will accept it :) thank you for your help!